# binding bean method to rendered jsf tag

Tags: jsf

I would like to know is there any way to hide/show links to certain pages by using the `rendered` jsf tag in conjunction with a bean method.
for eg. `rendered="#{sidebarController.isGrantedAcess("Admin")}` doesn't work

Comment: if you change the rendered attribute inside an ajax call then include the id of the affected component in the update (p:ajax)/render (f:ajax) attribute.

Comment: Add little bit more code what exactly you are doing ?